# "Broken Pipe" when uploading to Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading

I just got my Arduino UNO and I'm trying to upload the blink example but the upload fails with

```
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
```

I have tried both Arduino IDE 1.0.1 (which I installed via my package manager) as well as version 1.0.5 which I downloaded from the arduino.cc website. I'm running Ubuntu Linux 12.10 if that makes a difference.

I'd appreciate any and all help in getting my arduino up and running!

Comment: Are your drivers installed correctly? Did you double check the COM port? A quick Google search didn't return any results...

Comment: I got it working by switching USB port. I didn't even realize there is a green led that's on when the arduino is connected. So yes, I'm new to this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any communication error, try these:

- Disconnect and reconnect the USB cable.
- Use a different USB cable.
- Press the reset button on the board.
- Restart the Arduino IDE.
- Make sure you select the right board in `Tools ► Board ►`, e.g. If you are using the Duemilanove 328, select that instead of Duemilanove 128. The board should say what version it is on the microchip.
- Make sure you selected the right port in `Tools ► Serial Port ►`. One way to figure out which port it is on is by following these steps:

  1. Disconnect the USB cable.
  2. Go to `Tools ► Serial Port ►` and see which ports are listed (e.g. COM4 COM5 COM14).
  3. Reconnect the USB cable.
  4. Go back to `Tools ► Serial Port ►`, and see which port appeared that wasn't there before.
- In extreme cases, you may need to [burn the bootloader](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/474/37).

<sup><sub>Answer adapted from [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/18/37).</sub></sup>

Comment: The first point fixed this problem for me: Disconnect & reconnect (in a different port) the USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

### It sounds like you have incorrect drivers or the wrong COM port (USB) selected in the IDE

Both are easy to fix. I'd imagine that it would be the COM port.

[image: IDE]

To do this:

> Tools → Serial Port → [COM port... try a few different ones. Also you can use device manager to see which one disappears when you unplug your Arduino]

Few notes on photo:

#1. The selector for the COM port. Choose which one your board is on.

#2. That shows the COM port selected and board. I don't have my UNO connected: ignore that the COM port isn't showing up on the menu.