# Arduino Mega timeout communication with programmer error

Tags: bootloader, arduino-mega, avrdude

I have an Arduino Mega 2560 and it was working fine until about lunch time when I started getting this error:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

I know it isn't the code I'm running as I tried to load it onto an Uno and it seemed to load without issue. I need to use the Mega as it has more ports, though.

From what I have read this is potentially an issue with the bootloader and is possibly related to the current version of Arduino. I know virtually nothing about the bootloader; all I know is that it is used to upload code to the Arduino (I think...), therefore I have a fear of just messing around with related files unknowingly.

These pages are the ones I've been looking at, but like I said, I don't really know enough to feel comfortable with just messing around with the files.

- [Mega2560: timeout communicating with programmer....](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=135451.0)
- [Upload Timeout Error on Mega 2560 - Not Sure What Changed](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,83079.msg659993.html#msg659993)

I tried uninstalling my Mega totally, then reinstalling it. I also downloaded an older version of Arduino (0022) and neither option seemed to work.

I don't know what to do, or how to change the 'AVR' files if necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some dude named avr won't let me upload my program, aka "avrdude: stk500\_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00"](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/some-dude-named-avr-wont-let-me-upload-my-program-aka-avrdude-stk500-getsync)

Comment: Ohhh I didn't notice that post. I've tried everything except burning the bootloader... is there a simple way to do this without having to buy software?

Comment: usually you just go to the IDE, look under the tools menu, select "Burn Bootloader". Make sure to select the right board first.

Comment: @TheDoctor, I've seen that option, but I have no idea what to do afterwards. I presume I have to load it again with a new "bootloader" program? One site (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader) says I need to buy hardware and download specific software... all to replace the software on the bootloader?! I'm not sure I understand why.

Comment: I think the menu item is only for arduinos that have a progrmmer built in, like the Uno and Mega

Comment: So if I clicked that menu item... do you know what would happen? I don't want to do anything I don't understand just in case there is a simpler solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: This is the super-simple solution. buying hardware is a more complex task. Do you have any other arduinos?

Comment: I have an Uno, but I got the Mega because the Uno can't cope as well and doesn't have as many ports (it's used to control a robot vehicle)

Comment: You can use the Uno to reprogram the Mega. Look up `ArduinoISP`

Comment: Has something changed that means you can burn a bootloader without an ISP?

Comment: I've been having this exact issue with my Mega2560 lately. Click upload -> compiles -> upload begins (serial tx/rx blinking) -> avrdude timeout. But this is an intermittent problem. It uploads correctly maybe 20% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

The bootloader on an arduino is just a piece of software written to enable you to update your sketches using the usb connection. Without the bootloader you can't upload sketches using just the arduino ide.

More information about the bootloader can be found here: http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Environment?from=Tutorial.Bootloader
Look under the heading entitled uploading which explains the part the bootloader plays in uploading sketches.

When you use the "Burn Bootloader" button in the arduino ide it will attempt to write a new copy of the bootloader onto the attached Arduino board. To do this the board must be attached in a specific manner - that is - using the icsp/isp header rather than the usb cable.

Now to program the avr chip directly you have to use an external (hardware) programmer. Fortunately you don't have to buy one if you have a second arduino because the second arduino can be used as a programmer. Instructions for doing so can be found here: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Even more info about the bootloader: http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader?from=Main.Bootloader

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this error refers to many different issues and there are so many posts here and on other platforms none with a definite answer. Maybe Arduino team should try to give better errors to differentiate. But I have tried to answer the same question here in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645441/avrdude-stk500v2-receivemessage-timeout/45167540#45167540).

what solved my issue was to go to Tools>Boards>Board Manager... select "updatable" for "Type" on top left and then select the updatable packages below and click on update.

Comment: This resolved my issue. I selected the update for the board and that it

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error when my Arduino COM port was busy with other apps. I closed that app and upload Arduino sketch and error disappeared.