# avrdude : stk500_get sync<> attempt 10 of 10 not in sync : resp=0x20 how do i get pass this error for ardunio uno board

Tags: arduino-uno, avrdude, compile

When I first started with a bare minimum code. The compiler compiles the code, but when I try to upload, this is the error message I get:

```
 AVRDUDE: STK500_GETSYNC<> ATTEMPT 10 OF 10 NOT IN SYNC :RESP=0X20
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Search for: attempt 10 of 10 not in sync, in the search box on this page. This question is asked frequently.

Comment: See my lengthy post about [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno).

Also the popular question [Some dude named avr won't let me upload my program, aka “avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00”](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/some-dude-named-avr-wont-let-me-upload-my-program-aka-avrdude-stk500-getsync).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why you are getting this error.

1. Bootloader is either missing or corrupted. This is fairly unlikely.
2. Wire connected to pin 0 (RX)
3. Wrong COM port is chosen within the arduino IDE.
4. Drivers are not installed. You can update it within the Device Manager if you are using Windows.

Here is a link to an article explaining the causes and how to fix them, http://www.instructables.com/id/A-solution-to-avrdude-stk500getsync-not-in-syn/