# Trouble while using Arduino DUE as programmer

Tags: arduino-due, avrdude, arduinoisp

I'm trying to use the arduino DUE board as a  AVR Programmer. My target device is atmega328p. After uploading the ArduinoISP into the DUE Board. I've tried to let a pin toggle using the following code:

```
#define F_CPU 10000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


int main (){
    DDRD |= (1<< PD7);
    for(;;){
        PORTD ^= (1<< PD7);
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use the internal oscillator and based [this example](https://gist.github.com/holachek/3304890)  I've adjust the makefile:

```
DEVICE     = atmega328p
CLOCK      = 8000000
PROGRAMMER = -c arduino -P COM10 -b 19200 
OBJECTS    = main.o
FUSES      = -U lfuse:w:0x62:m -U hfuse:w:0xd9:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m
```

the problem that I have is that when run :

```
make flash
```

I get the following :

[image]

and yes the port COM10 is definitely correct.

does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: What are the fuses on the Atmega328P? And does it have a bootloader? You can [find out this stuff](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) if you have a spare Uno or similar around.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because questions about avrdude errors that are long abandoned without followup from the asker are effectively unanswerable.

Comment: As there's a chance a specific keyword combination will direct people here from Google, I think it's better if it's marked as duplicate, so there's a link on top of the page that contains possible steps to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There error you have is from *avrdude* failing to get a communication link established to the 'programmer' (which manipulates the target.)

Here is a link that may help with the connection

[Stk500 error](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won)

Here is another relative link that may help

[Arduino ISP on DUE](https://petervanhoyweghen.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/arduinoisp-on-the-due/)

Best of luck.