# stk500 getsync() attempt 10 of 10 atmega328pu

Tags: arduino-ide, atmega328

I've been getting this very common error on my atmega328pu circuit.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x83

Some things iv'e tried are:

- Restarting my comp
- Reuploading the bootloader
- Redownloading old version of arduino IDE
- Using an FTDI chip and placing the chip inside an Uno

After I bootloaded the chip I was able to upload a blink sketch. Then the next time I tried I got this error. Anyone know what could be up? This is driving me crazy!

[image: Circuit as built]

Comment: Where is the edge detector on the reset line? Where are the decoupling caps?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/22541/11529 Does this answer help?