# Arduino_Debug doesn't successfully upload sketch to Arduino if JAVA is not installed

Tags: arduino-due, debug

I use `arduino_debug` to upload my sketch to an Arduino Mega 2560 and to an Arduino Due from my application (Windows).

I saw the following issue:

When JAVA is not installed or it was installed only after the Arduino SW installation, the command:

```
arduino_debug --port COM6 --upload mysketch.ino
```

doesn't successfully to upload the sketch. My Arduino is connected to `COM6` (I verified it) and the sketch's path is correct.

I got the following output:

```
Initializing packages...

Preparing boards...

Verifying...

Sketch uses 6222 bytes (19%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 318 bytes (15%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1730 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

Uploading...

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87

An error occurred while uploading the sketch

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87
```

Has anyone seen this issue? Does anyone know why JAVA must be installed?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/17/33608)

Comment: `arduino_debug.exe` is a build of Arduino IDE to debug the Arduino IDE. So normally you should use `arduino.exe` command for CLI too. The Arduino IDE is a Java application. It has Java bundled in installation. In your case I would guess that the reset of the board is not invoked for some Java related reason.

Comment: The error message is not related to Java, it's usually either wrong COM port being selected, wrong bootloader or a temporary glitch that resolves when you try to reupload.