# Atmega328p and cp2102 with error avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I recently bought a usb/ttl cp2102 converter for testing with a standalone Atmega328p, I made the DTR connection with the pin 1 in the Atmega  using a ceramic capacitor of 0.10uf (104) so that when I send my code to my Atmega standalone it save the code without having to worry about the reset. However, when trying to send it the first time it worked and the other attempts failed, it seems that whenever I restart the computer and turn it on again it sends the code to the Atmega and in the other attempts it fails.
To try to solve I tested with IDE Arduino 1.8.5 and 1.8.9 in Linux Mint and Windows 10 and gave the same problem, I recorded the bootloader again and did not solve.

The error that appears in the output of the IDE is this:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

From what I read, this error is generic and hardly helps to solve the error.

Comment: What qualifies as "it works" and "it fails"?  It is hard to understand the meaning of your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["avrdude: stk500\_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00," aka Some Dude Named Avr Won't Let Me Upload My Program](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching a little and found the solution! In addition to capacitor 104, its necessari need to add a 10k resistor by connecting the 5 volts to pin 1.

This is the link of the GitHub project where I found the solution with the assembly scheme, I hope this helps somebody else!

https://github.com/leonvandenbeukel/Arduino-on-a-breadboard/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Your problem was that you left the reset floating.