# I cannot upload any code to my arduino nano

Tags: arduino-nano

Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P"

Sketch uses 934 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

An error occurred while uploading the sketch

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: Do you have the right COM port selected? Is your Nano a cheap chinese clone that may not even have the bootloader installed (I have had that before...)? Has it ever worked, or is this your first attempt with this board?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["avrdude: stk500\_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00," aka Some Dude Named Avr Won't Let Me Upload My Program](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won)

Comment: First try the "Old bootloader" answer

Comment: The old boot loader fixed it for me. A lot of the Chinese boards I used have that issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me selecting the `ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)` from the **Tools** --> **Processor** menu in the Arduino IDE solved the problem.

See: https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2020/10/16/arduino-programmer-is-not-responding-not-in-sync-error/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an Arduino Micro. When the upload starts, press once the reset button.