# Arduino Uno Clone Error Compilig AVRDUDE

Tags: arduino-uno

Can anyone please help me with this error?

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sketch uses 2964 bytes (9%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.

Global variables use 89 bytes (4%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1959 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcd



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

With enabled a in comment:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila, ATmega168"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:diecimila:cpu=atmega168 -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10813 -build-path C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_250344 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose D:\Downloads Chrome\sketch_apr20a\sketch_apr20a.ino

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:diecimila:cpu=atmega168 -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10813 -build-path C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_250344 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose D:\Downloads Chrome\sketch_apr20a\sketch_apr20a.ino

Using board 'diecimila' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr

Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr

Detecting libraries used...

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega168 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\standard" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\sketch\\sketch_apr20a.ino.cpp" -o nul -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE

Alternatives for Servo.h: [Servo@1.1.6 Servo@1.1.3]

ResolveLibrary(Servo.h)

  -> candidates: [Servo@1.1.6 Servo@1.1.3]

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega168 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\standard" "-ID:\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\Servo\\src" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\sketch\\sketch_apr20a.ino.cpp" -o nul -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE

Using cached library dependencies for file: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\avr\Servo.cpp

Using cached library dependencies for file: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\megaavr\Servo.cpp

Using cached library dependencies for file: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\nrf52\Servo.cpp

Using cached library dependencies for file: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\sam\Servo.cpp

Using cached library dependencies for file: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\samd\Servo.cpp

Using cached library dependencies for file: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\stm32f4\Servo.cpp

Generating function prototypes...

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega168 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\standard" "-ID:\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\Servo\\src" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\sketch\\sketch_apr20a.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp" -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

Compiling sketch...

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega168 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\standard" "-ID:\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\Servo\\src" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\sketch\\sketch_apr20a.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\sketch\\sketch_apr20a.ino.cpp.o"

Compiling libraries...

Compiling library "Servo"

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\libraries\Servo\avr\Servo.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\libraries\Servo\megaavr\Servo.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\libraries\Servo\nrf52\Servo.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\libraries\Servo\sam\Servo.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\libraries\Servo\samd\Servo.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\libraries\Servo\stm32f4\Servo.cpp.o

Compiling core...

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\wiring_pulse.S.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\hooks.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\WInterrupts.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\wiring.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\wiring_analog.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\wiring_shift.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\wiring_digital.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\wiring_pulse.c.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\CDC.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\HardwareSerial1.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\PluggableUSB.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\HardwareSerial3.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\HardwareSerial.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\IPAddress.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\HardwareSerial2.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\HardwareSerial0.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\WMath.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\Print.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\WString.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\abi.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\Stream.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\Tone.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\new.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\USBCore.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\main.cpp.o

Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669\core\core.a

Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_250344\core\core_arduino_avr_diecimila_cpu_atmega168_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a

Linking everything together...

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega168 -o "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669/sketch_apr20a.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\sketch\\sketch_apr20a.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\libraries\\Servo\\avr\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\libraries\\Servo\\megaavr\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\libraries\\Servo\\nrf52\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\libraries\\Servo\\sam\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\libraries\\Servo\\samd\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669\\libraries\\Servo\\stm32f4\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669/core\\core.a" "-LC:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669" -lm

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669/sketch_apr20a.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669/sketch_apr20a.ino.eep"

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669/sketch_apr20a.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669/sketch_apr20a.ino.hex"

Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h"

 Used: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo

 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Servo

Using library Servo at version 1.1.3 in folder: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo 

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-size" -A "C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_293669/sketch_apr20a.ino.elf"

Sketch uses 2964 bytes (20%) of program storage space. Maximum is 14336 bytes.

Global variables use 89 bytes (8%) of dynamic memory, leaving 935 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 1024 bytes.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega168 -carduino -PCOM4 -b19200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_293669/sketch_apr20a.ino.hex:i 



avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch



         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"



         Using Port                    : COM4

         Using Programmer              : arduino

         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x62



avrdude done.  Thank you.



Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

'''
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you add the error message with `verbose output during compilation` as instructed at the end of the error message. Is it an original Arduino or a Clone? And possible duplicate of [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won) post.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the `Clone` in the title and can't edit my comment now.

Comment: Hi, i updated my post. Would you mind checking it again? Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the weblink in the error message? Have you checked the Stackexchange post and the answers I linked to?

Comment: `Board: "Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila, ATmega168"` is not Uno. what did you select in Tools menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["avrdude: stk500\_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00," aka Some Dude Named Avr Won't Let Me Upload My Program](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won)

Comment: @Juraj Already linked it, see my first comment.

Comment: i already checked the link before submitting a post here but the post's solutions do not work

Comment: Did you change the board to UNO, as @Juraj said? In the second error message the selected board is a `Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila, ATmega168`, not a UNO as you said in the title and in the first error message.

Comment: More words. Explain what board you actually have, the process your going through, and make sure the listings in your question match the output of the steps described.  If it the answer is as simple as "I selected the wrong board" you can just delete your question rather than letting it float around in the system forever being of no use to anyone else.

Comment: Hi, i have an arduino uno. the reason why the board was diecimila was that i found a thread before posting here that changing the board to the latter will somehow fix the issue. I already installed a driver for the board and my computer can read it, i just am not able to upload codes within it. I tried playing with the boards and programmers but nothing works, and yes i changed it back to the default yet still, it has the same problem. Thank you