# avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding Arduino LCD_I2C Upload problem ( port not found and ...)

Tags: i2c, lcd, error

i have problem to upload the LCD I2c Example program to Arduino UNo. the code are shown below:

```
//YWROBOT
//Compatible with the Arduino IDE 1.0
//Library version:1.1
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 
  lcd.init();
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
  lcd.print("Hello, world!");
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print("Ywrobot Arduino!");
   lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("Arduino LCM IIC 2004");
   lcd.setCursor(2,3);
  lcd.print("Power By Ec-yuan!");
}


void loop()
{
}
```

the schematic is like the below photo:

[image]

but i get this error:

```
Sketch uses 3382 bytes (10%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 327 bytes (15%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1721 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Thank.

Comment: try uploading some other sketch ... you will find that it is not `problem to upload the LCD I2c Example program`, it is `problem uploading any program`

Comment: Thanks @chrisl, the [avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00," aka Some Dude Named Avr Won't Let Me Upload My Program](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won) helped me, the problem was solved by **changing the USB Cable** and **removing the I2C pins from the Arduino Pins** ( SCL & SDA Pins : A4 and A5).

Comment: @jsotola, the Problem was only with **upload the LCD I2c Example program**, and solved by the above solution (  **changing the USB Cable** and **removing the I2C pins from the Arduino Pins** )

Comment: @sosa are you saying that other programs would load correctly without changing the USB cable and removing I2C pins?

Comment: @jsotola, if i have not removed the SCL and SCA pints, Yes.