# Arduino Pro Mini & FTDI USB can't upload sketh

Tags: uploading, avrdude, arduino-mini

As the title says, I have an Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V & FTDI FT232RL that I connected to the arduino board. It worked for a while, on and off but the serial monitor wasn't working. Fixed that by using 57600 baud rate but now I get these errors. I tried multiple things from [this][1] post but they didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x53
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xec
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x71
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x87
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x60
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe8
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x7d
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd0
Failed chip erase: uploading error: exit status 1


  [1]: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won
```